# Example of a product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I've been researching [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Product_%CF%83-algebra) of the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Could someone provide me with a concrete example. For example, if $S=\{1,2\}, T=\{2,3\}$ and we take the $\sigma$ algebras of both to be their respective power sets, then what would be the product $\sigma$-algebra of $S \times T$?

Comment: [These lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch5.pdf) might be helpful providing the definition and example.

Answer (score 2):

That example is a bit too trivial IMO. Any set of the form $\{(s,t)\}$ where $(s,t) \in S \times T$ is a measurable rectangle, $\{s\} \times \{t\}$, so in the product $\sigma$-algebra. It follows, as everything is a finite union of singletons, that the product $\sigma$-algebra on $S \times T$ is also just the power set.

Maybe the finite-cofinite algebra on $\Bbb R$, and its square, are more interesting...